# Bigquery lookup prev month

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need a way to retune a row if the query is not found from the next month when it was found. For example, my Query:

```
    SELECT
    query,
    date_trunc(report_date, month) as report_month,
    SUM(clicks) AS clicks,
    SUM(impressions) AS impressions,
    SUM(clicks) / SUM(impressions) AS ctr,
    ROUND(AVG(position),0) AS position,
    ROUND(lag(AVG(position)) over (partition by query order by min(report_date)),0) as position_prev,
    (SUM(clicks) * SUM(impressions))  * (AVG(position) / 1000) AS visibility,
    lag((SUM(clicks) * SUM(impressions))  * (AVG(position) / 1000)) over (partition by query order by min(report_date)) as visibility_prev

FROM
  `table`

WHERE 
    search_type = "web" and
    search_appearance is null and 
    country ="aus" and query = "24 hour electrician fremantle"

GROUP BY
    report_month, query

ORDER BY report_month
```

which returns

[image]

but it would be nice to return another row for June 21 to show status are nill and last month stats as other rows.

Is this possible in BQ without having to create a script?

example rows below:
[image]

Comment: Meaning you'd like for all months to have a row regardless if they have data?

Comment: correct or at least one of the following months so I can check for instances where visibility and visibility_prev are both null - meaning the query was lost.

Comment: could you please add some examples line of you table, so I can create the query with correct fields and properly.

Comment: @ewertonvsilva - i have updated with an example. thanks in advance.

Comment: just to clarify im looking to return a 3rd row in the example above. with the query "24 hour electrician" on the month of 2021-06-01 where all values all null except visibility_prev to show value from prev month.

Answer (score 1):

To not having to change your original query, put it on a with statement and run the following over it. Use the `report_month between date(<begin>) and date(<end>)`to choose all months you want to return.

```sql
-- Your query on a with statement
with table_ as (
    SELECT
    query,
    date_trunc(report_date, month) as report_month,
    SUM(clicks) AS clicks,
    SUM(impressions) AS impressions,
    SUM(clicks) / SUM(impressions) AS ctr,
    ROUND(AVG(position),0) AS position,
    ROUND(lag(AVG(position)) over (partition by query order by min(report_date)),0) as position_prev,
    (SUM(clicks) * SUM(impressions))  * (AVG(position) / 1000) AS visibility,
    lag((SUM(clicks) * SUM(impressions))  * (AVG(position) / 1000)) over (partition by query order by min(report_date)) as visibility_prev

FROM
  `table`

WHERE 
    search_type = "web" and
    search_appearance is null and 
    country ="aus" and query = "24 hour electrician fremantle"

GROUP BY
    report_month, query

ORDER BY report_month
)
----------------------------------
select 
    if(t0.query is null, "24 hour electrician fremantle", t0.query) as query,
    t1.report_month, 
    t0.clicks, 
    t0.impressions,
    t0.ctr, 
    t0.position,
    (select position from table_ where report_month=date_sub(t1.report_month, interval 1 month)) position_prev,
    t0.visibility,
    (select visibility from table_ where report_month=date_sub(t1.report_month, interval 1 month)) visibility_prev 
from 
    table_ t0
full join 
    (select * from unnest(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY("2021-01-01", "2021-12-01", INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS report_month
    where
    -- Use the following to choose all months you want, to perform to entire year set date("2021-01-01") and date("2021-12-01")
    report_month between date("2021-04-01") and date("2021-06-01")) t1
on
    t0.report_month = t1.report_month
order by 
    report_month
```

Results:
[image]

results with report_month between date("2021-01-01") and date("2021-10-01"):

[image]

Comment: thankyou! can this query be modified to run on a table with multiple queries? so that It performs the result in the first output (single month) for all queries.

Comment: could you please specify it better with some example ?